# Parsing sub-properties from a list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, list-comprehension

In Python (2.7), I am parsing a list of dictionaries (that come from JSON) where each dictionary has the following format (I'm using fake key names):

`{'k': {'p': value_i_care_about_1, 'q': value_i_care_about_2, ... (stuff I don't want)}, ... (stuff I don't want)}`

where `...` represents key-value pairs I don't care about (*do not want*).

I need to parse this into a list of tuples where each tuple has the following format:

`(value_i_care_about_1, value_i_care_about_2)`

If this were Mathematica for instance, I could iterate over the list of dictionaries with `Map` or `Table` (doesn't really matter) and for each dictionary extract the two keys I want into a list with this code (where `dicts` represents the list of dicts):

`#[['k', {'p', 'q'}]]& /@ dicts` (in Mathematica you use `[[]]` for indexing because `[]` is used for function calls).

As of now, in Python I am using the following code

`[(d['k']['p'], d['k']['q'])) for d in dicts]`

However, in addition to violating DRY a little bit (I'm a bit of a DRY nut), with the full key names, this goes way over PEP 8's line limit of 79 characters. I'm just wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Thanks.

EDIT: Please see the line under the format of the dictionaries about `...`

Comment: Why don't you use `dict.values()` in order to get the all values at once?

Comment: From my question: "where `...` represents key-value pairs I don't care about."

Essentially, I only need 2 values from the dictionary, but it has a whole bunch at both levels that I don't want.

Comment: You can indent to your heart's delight inside of a list comprehension if you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I may have to just go with that :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is longer, but it has the benefit of being relatively legible and simply extendable.

```
# you can add any combination of fields here
fields = [['k', 'p'], 
          ['k', 'q']]
result = [tuple(d[level1][level2] for level1, level2 in fields)
          for d in dicts]
```

Comment: WE NEED TUPLE COMPREHENSIONS! I ended up just splitting the line by assigning the long level 2 key names to variables (there's only 1 level 1 key), but this might come in handy in the future, and would definitely get rid of the DRY issue. I think, however,  it may be too much for this particular situation. Regardless, it does answer every requirement of the question, so I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering of p and q isn't important, and if k is constant across all dicts (in order to shorten the line):

```
key = 'k'
[(d[key].values()) for d in dicts]
```

If the ordering in your tuple does matter you'll have to do it your way, though if the names are constant again you could split that out to shorten the line:

```
key = 'k'
key1, key2 = 'text of p', 'text of q'
```

This double reference to the top level is unavoidable if order is necessary, because python dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Shame that the double reference is unavoidable. However, your answer will not work because as I mentioned, each level is full of key value pairs that I do not want.

Comment: You're right, I see I missed that part.  For some reason I thought the extra values were at the level of k.  If the ordering is important it wouldn't work anyway.  Well, at least if you can split out the key names on an earlier line that would save you horizontal length.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for a 'Pythonic' way to get for each 'k' a list of inner values.
So, for this you might want to use the following code, it is not depend on a given key/keys:

```
json = {'k1': {'p': 'value_i_care_about_1', 'q': 'value_i_care_about_2'},
'k2':{'p': 'value_i_care_about_3', 'q': 'value_i_care_about_4'}}

l = {k: [y for (x,y) in v.items()] for (k,v) in json.items()}
print (l['k1'])
print (l['k2'])
```

> Output: 
>   ['value_i_care_about_1', 'value_i_care_about_2'] 
>   ['value_i_care_about_3', 'value_i_care_about_4']

Comment: I've mentioned this a few times, so maybe the use of `...` was confusing. I *do not* want the other key value pairs at either level from this dict, even though there are many.

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY off with this nested list comprehension:

```
result = [tuple(dd[k1][k2] for k1 in ['k'] for k2 in ['p','q']) for dd in dictlist]
```